# Grails springsecurity ldap show logged username

Tags: grails, groovy, ldap

In my config.groovy I have some code for LDAP authentication using springsecurity plugin.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = CN=user,OU=Accounts,OU=Users,DC=organization,DC=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://ldapserver.com:389/'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.ignorePartialResultException = true // typically needed for Active Directory
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'DC=organization,DC=com'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.filter="(&(sAMAccountName={0})(|(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)(memberOf=...)))"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames=['ldapAuthProvider']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
   '/**': ['isFullyAuthenticated()']
]
```

It works fine but now I need to display logged username on main page and whichever user is logged, doing some actions. How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried [`<sec:username/>`](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/helperClasses.html#securityTagLib)?

> **username**
>
> Displays the value of the UserDetails username field if logged in.

```
 <sec:ifLoggedIn>
     Welcome Back <sec:username/>!
 </sec:ifLoggedIn>
 <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
     <g:link controller='login' action='auth'>Login</g:link>
 </sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @theghostofc thanks, i have added a quote from the docs there.  yet the question is very vague, so i didn't want to put to much efford in it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I you want to get the username in a service or controller, you should use:

```
def springSecurityService

def someActionOrMethod(){
  println springSecurityService.currentUser.username
}
```